# Sudoku Code Program - Checking Rows,Columns, and Boxes

Tags: java, user-input, sudoku, puzzle

I need help checking rows, columns, and boxes for a Sudoku program. I am a high school student that needs help completing this project. If any one could provide help that would be awesome! I am currently working on checking boxes where I have a comment saying "Start Here". Thanks!

```
import java.util.*;
public class Run
{
    Scanner scanner = new Scanner(System.in);
    
    public static void main(String[] args)
    {
        char [][] board = new char [9][9];
    
    
        Scanner scanner = new Scanner(System.in);
    
        System.out.println("Welcome to Sudoku!\n");
        fill(board);
        printBoard(board);
        inputLengthandDigits(board);
        System.out.println();
        printBoard(board);
        
    }
    
    public static void fill(char[][] arr){   
        for(int row = 0; row < arr.length; row++){
            for(int col= 0; col< arr[row].length; col++){
                arr[row][col] = '-';
            }
        }
    }

    public static void printBoard(char [][] array)
    {
        for(char[] row: array)
        {
            for(char play: row)
            {
                System.out.print(play+ " ");
            }
            System.out.println();
        }
    }
    
     public static void inputLengthandDigits(char[][] array){
        Scanner in = new Scanner(System.in);
        for (int i = 0; i < 9; i++) 
        {
            System.out.println("\nEnter the numbers in row " + (i+1) + ":");
            String input = in.nextLine();
            String numbers = "123456789-";
            boolean numberscheck = false;
            boolean endCheck = true;
            boolean onlyOnce = true;
            
            //Input Validation Starts Here!
            //Checks if Input is only digits 0-9
            do{

                if(endCheck==false){
                    System.out.println("\nPlease input numbers only (1-9)!");
                    input = in.nextLine();
                }
                
                if(onlyOnce==false){
                    System.out.println("\nPlease input numbers only once!");
                    input = in.nextLine();
                }
                
                //Checks Length of User Input
                while(input.length() < 9 || input.length() > 9){
                    System.out.println("\nPlease input 9 numbers!");
                    input = in.nextLine();
                }
                
                //Start Here 
                for(int a = 0; a<input.length()-1; a++){
                    for(int b= a + 1; b<input.length(); b++){
                        if(input.charAt(a)==input.charAt(b)){
                            onlyOnce = false;
                        }
                    }
                }
                
                
                for(int x = 0; x < input.length(); x++){
                    char thing = input.charAt(x);
                    numberscheck = false;
                    
                    for(int y = 0; y < numbers.length(); y++){
                        char numbersn = numbers.charAt(y);
                        if(thing == numbersn){
                            numberscheck = true;
                            endCheck = true;
                            break;
                        }
                    }
                    if(numberscheck == false){
                        endCheck = false;
                        break;
                    }
                }
            }while(endCheck==false || onlyOnce==false);
            
            
        

            for(int j=0; j<9; j++){
                array[i][j] = input.charAt(j);
            }
        }
     }
}
```

Comment: You may want to add the most important tag identifying the programming language.

Comment: What's your question? Does the program work? If it doesn't work, what do you expect it to do, and what is it doing instead?

Comment: Please see: [Why is “Can someone help me?” not an actual question?](http://meta.stackoverflow.com/q/284236)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

My initial response is too long for a comment.  I'm not sure I have a solution to your problem, largely because you haven't actually pointed out which bit is a problem yet, but these pointers should help improve things anyway:

1. Please reformat your code.  It is actually quite painful to look at.  Spaces should be used consistently around variables, key words, brackets and operands.  Opening curly braces should be on the same line as the method signature, for() loop or whatever else comes first.  You have random blank lines within methods which don't separate logical sections so are just confusing.  The compiler won't care about any of this, but if you can make your code look neater people will instinctively presume you care and are more likely to credit you with the ability to write decent code.
2. You have declared a new scanner variable three times.  This is redundant and wasteful clutter.  Either have a single, class-wide scanner, or (preferably), only create a scanner in a method which actually uses it and then remember to call scanner.close() once the scanner is no longer required.
3. inputLengthandDigits is a weird name.  Is 'Lengthand' a single word, or should it be 'inputLengtHandDigits' or 'inputLengthAndDigits'?  In camel case, capitalise every word except the first to make the whole easier to read.  Whatever it should be, I don't understand from the name what this method does.  It isn't inputting anything, it's getting inputs from someone else.  Perhaps getData or populateGrid might be more explanatory.
4. 9 appears quite a few times, with no explanation.  I know where it came from, because I spend far too much time playing Sudoku, but it is a magic number and these are to be avoided at all costs.  I met a magic number in the workplace once, wasted half a day trying to do what could have been a ten minute job if colleagues had recorded what the number was and where it came from.  Here, just have a `private static final int maxNumber = 9;` statement.
5. A good thing: your main() method has almost no fiddly details in it.  You have effectively used method calls to tell a story and describe what is happening elsewhere.  This is a really, really good thing to do :)
6. Some of your logic tests can be tidied up a bit, e.g. `!onlyOnce` is the same as `onlyOnce == false`, and `input.length() < maxNumber || input.length() > maxNumber` can be simplified to `input.length() != maxNumber`.  It's exactly the same logic, but faster to type and easier to read :)
7. It looks like your code under the //Start here comment is checking that you don't have any duplicate numbers.  If you do get duplicate numbers, the program is still going to try and run the next bit of code before asking the user for alternative input.  Is that something you want to happen, or a waste of time?
8. I actually burst out laughing when I saw a variable called 'thing'.  Please, find a name which actually describes the purpose of this variable.
9. I have now run the code, and it rightly pointed out an error when I tried to key in duplicate numbers for row 4.  However, it's now stuck there and keeps asking me to try again even when I put in a valid set of digits.  This needs to be fixed.  Look closely at which flags are triggering the request to retry.  Run your code in debugging mode (you are using an IDE like IntelliJ or Eclipse, aren't you?) and deliberately enter a bad row to see the behaviour for yourself and where the logic is going wrong.
10. This whole method to get the row input, validate it, and then populate the array, is very big and confusing.  You need to refactor it into a lot of smaller methods.  Here is a suggestion to play with:

```
private static char[][] populateGrid(char[][] array) {
  Scanner scanner = new Scanner(System.in);

  for (int i = 0; i <maxNumber; i++) {
    String rowData = getRowInput(scanner);
    populateRow(array, rowNumber, rowData);
  }

  scanner.close;
  return array;
}

private static String getRowInput(Scanner scanner) {
    System.out.println("\nEnter the numbers in row " + (i + 1) + ":");
    String input = scanner.nextLine();
    while (!isValidInput(input) {
      System.out.println("Please enter only the digits 1-9 in any order, with no duplicates or omissions");
      input = scanner.nextLine();
    }
    return input;
}

private static boolean isValidInput(String input) {
  if (!rightLengthOfInput(input)) {
    return false;
  }
  if (!allUniqueDigits(input)) {
    return false;
  }
  if (!usesCorrectCharacters(input)) {
    return false;
  }
  return true;
}
```

I'll leave you to make the different input validation methods.  It will largely be a case of moving your existing code, but the method names will help humans understand what each section is doing.  This structure also allows you to cleanly add more validation checks, should such a thing be desired in the future.

Things to consider after all that:

- Are you going to check that you have a viable Sudoku solution, or will you trust the user to put in correct data such that the columns also have each of the nine digits in them?  How will you handle an invalid grid, e.g. each row is identical?
- How far does this assignment want you to go?  Do you need to systematically remove numbers to get a solvable puzzle rather than a completed grid?  Will the assignment stop at a puzzle which can be seen in the console, or do you need a printable format, or will the user be able to play through the program?  If the latter option, will this be in the console or using a graphical interface?

I appreciate that there is a lot to think about and work on here.  Take it steadily, one step at a time, and keep asking questions if you need too.

Comment: This kind of answer would be suitable if the question were asked on http://codereview.stackexchange.com/ - Stack Overflow is meant for answers to specific programming questions, not really meant for general, open-ended feedback. In this case the OP is not asking a specific programming question so it is not really possible to write a good answer. Please see [How to Answer](https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-answer), particularly the section on answering "well-asked questions".

Comment: kaya3, I would often agree with you.  However, I noted that our questioner here is new.  My own experience as a fledgling programmer is that it can be hard to find the right support and encouragement, and to learn how to ask the right question.  Hence, I am far more lenient with a newcomer to this community than some others might be, even if not everyone likes that approach.